# FrameLabel function does not label my graph

Tags: list-manipulation, graphics, frame

I am using the Show function to graph two functions I previously plotted with ListPlot. I used FrameLabel to name my axis, but it does not work. [image]

Comment: Those are probably axes and not frames, technically. Try adding the Options: `Axes -> None, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}` then playing around with the `FrameLabel` option.

Comment: You need `AxesLabel` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `Show` with `Labeled`

```
graph1 = ListPlot[Range@10, PlotStyle -> Green];
graph2 = ListPlot[Reverse@Range@10, PlotStyle -> Red];

Labeled[
  Show[{graph1, graph2}, BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}],
    {"xxx", "yyy"},
    {Bottom, Left},
    RotateLabel -> True]
```

[image]

If you want to use `FrameLabel` you have to specify `Frame`:

```
ListPlot[{Range@10, Reverse@Range@10},
 BaseStyle -> {18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
 PlotStyle -> {Green, Red},
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
 FrameLabel -> {"xxx", "yyy"}]
```

[image]